# List of users that modified by a single Opportunity record

Tags: soql

I have one opportunity record which is shared to 4 users in my organization. Any one can login and change the opportunity status.

I have to find list of users that modified that particular record.

I tried with LastModifiedById but i am getting only last user modified Id only.

```
SELECT opp.LastModifiedById FROM Opportunity opp WHERE Id = '002232332dwwsds'
```

How to retrieve all the users that modifies the opportunity record?

Comment: Enable field history tracking for the fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best solution for this is to enable Field History tracking on the fields where it is most important to see who changed them and then Salesforce will automatically log the change to the fields and who changed them.

You enable field history tracking from the Setup->Build->Customise->Opportunity->Fields and click the 'Set History Tracking' button.

Comment: Thank you. I set the Field History for some of the important fields on opportunity.  I have done query like as follow , i am able to see all the changes and corresponding user id's(o.CreatedById ) as well. Thank you \n       -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                     Select o.OpportunityId, o.OldValue, o.NewValue, o.IsDeleted, o.Id, o.Field, o.CreatedDate, o.CreatedById From OpportunityFieldHistory o where  o.OpportunityId='006S044545SDFS'             -------

Comment: Good to hear it. Please mark my answer as accepted so it comes out of the list of unanswered questions.